# mysql conversion from varchar to DATETIME with UTC TimeZone

Tags: mysql

Example varchar is stored like `2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530`

How can I convert it to `DATETIME` using `str_to_date()` with no loss of any data?

Comment: In which timezone do you plan to store your information?

Comment: "How can I convert it to DATETIME using str_to_date() with no loss of any data?"..You can't DATETIME stores data in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]` format unless you calculate the timezone difference on the go.... with to function `CONVERT_TZ`

Answer (score 2):

You could go for something like this. 
Calculating the datetime on the go with CONVERT_TZ. 
Note that use must use your own timezone i've used +00:00 that is GMT

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , CONVERT_TZ(DATETIME, '+00:00', CONCAT(SIGN, HOUR, ":00")) AS datetime_calculated
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(LEFT('2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530', 23), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s.%f') AS DATETIME
    , SUBSTRING('2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530', 24, 1) AS SIGN
    , CAST(SUBSTRING('2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530', 25, 2) AS SIGNED) AS HOUR
) AS date_parsed
```

**Result**

```
datetime                    sign      hour  datetime_calculated         
--------------------------  ------  ------  ----------------------------
2018-05-12 12:02:30.400000  +            5  2018-05-12 17:02:30.400000
```

EDIT because off comment:

**create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE example_datetime (
  DATETIME VARCHAR(255) 
);

INSERT INTO example_datetime VALUES('2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530');
INSERT INTO example_datetime VALUES('2017-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530');
INSERT INTO example_datetime VALUES('2016-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530');
INSERT INTO example_datetime VALUES('2015-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , CONVERT_TZ(DATETIME, '+00:00', CONCAT(SIGN, HOUR, ":00")) AS datetime_calculated
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
      DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(example_datetime.datetime, 23), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s.%f') AS DATETIME
    , SUBSTRING(example_datetime.datetime, 24, 1) AS SIGN
    , CAST(SUBSTRING(example_datetime.datetime, 25, 2) AS SIGNED) AS HOUR
   FROM
     example_datetime   
) AS date_parsed
```

**Result**

```
DATETIME                    SIGN      HOUR  datetime_calculated  
--------------------------  ------  ------  ---------------------
2018-05-12 12:02:30.400000  +            5  2018-05-12 17:02:30  
2017-05-12 12:02:30.400000  +            5  2017-05-12 17:02:30  
2016-05-12 12:02:30.400000  +            5  2016-05-12 17:02:30  
2015-05-12 12:02:30.400000  +            5  2015-05-12 17:02:30
```

**EDIT with update query**

**Query**

```
UPDATE 
 example_datetime
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
   *
   , CONVERT_TZ(DATETIME_format, '+00:00', CONCAT(SIGN, HOUR, ":00")) AS datetime_calculated
  FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        example_datetime.datetime 
      , DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(example_datetime.datetime, 23), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s.%f') AS DATETIME_format
      , SUBSTRING(example_datetime.datetime, 24, 1) AS SIGN
      , CAST(SUBSTRING(example_datetime.datetime, 25, 2) AS SIGNED) AS HOUR
    FROM
     example_datetime   
  ) AS date_parsed 
) 
 AS date_parsed 
SET 
  example_datetime.datetime = date_parsed.datetime_calculated
WHERE
  example_datetime.datetime = date_parsed.datetime
```

**Result**

```
Query: UPDATE example_datetime INNER JOIN ( SELECT * , CONVERT_TZ(DATETIME_format, '+00:00', CONCAT(SIGN, HOUR, ":00")) AS datetime_cal...

4 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.012 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.013 sec
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM example_datetime
```

**Result**

```
DATETIME             
---------------------
2018-05-12 17:02:30  
2017-05-12 17:02:30  
2016-05-12 17:02:30  
2015-05-12 17:02:30
```

Comment: but this converts a sample varchar like  '2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530' to datetime how shall I convert a table containing  many varchar date rows to datetime with UTC info as shown above?can you suggest me some logic for it?

Comment: @Aravind Sarja edited the question so it has a table example.. The SQL code should make it clear on how to make it work when the data is within a table.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond for your suggestions ,but this is not I am looking for ..I want to convert existing varchar datatype rows in to DATETIME using update and set querry for example something like this ....                                                      .update exclusion
set appliedFrom = 
CAST(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(appliedFrom', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'), '+00:00', 
 CONCAT(SUBSTRING(appliedFrom, 24, 1), CAST(SUBSTRING('2018-10-29T12:02:30.400+0000', 25, 2) AS SIGNED), ":", SUBSTRING('appliedFrom, 27, 3))) AS DATETIME)  where appliedfrom is of varchar type

Comment: actually there are 1000s of rows with date values stored as varchar in the table .I want to update all those rows in to proper date format (with UTC info) and then alter table from varchar type to datetime

Comment: In the above example you are showing how to select it but, I want to update table

Comment: I want to do something like this.....................................................................          .update exclusion ex1,
(
SELECT 
CAST(CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(appliedFrom, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'), '+00:00', 
 CONCAT(SUBSTRING(appliedFrom, 24, 1), CAST(SUBSTRING(appliedFrom, 25, 2) AS SIGNED), ":", SUBSTRING(appliedFrom, 27, 3))) AS DATETIME) AS datetime_calculated,exclusionId from exclusion
)ex2
set ex1.appliedFromDate = ex2.datetime_calculated
where ex1.exclusionId = ex2.exclusionId
 but it gives me error

Comment: It gives me error Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530'

Comment: @Aravind Sarja i notice that even the query `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'); ` generates a warning with SHOW WARNINGS `Warning    1292  Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530'`  But the query `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LEFT('2018-05-12T12:02:30.400+0530', 23), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f');` didn't generate the warning....  Try your update query with  `DATE_FORMAT(LEFT(appliedFrom, 23), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')`

Comment: @Aravind Sarja edited mine answer with a update query with the LEFT (like advised in the last comment) function and it works like a charm... you need to change the WHERE statement so it's using your exclusionId... but sure the create and test this query on a test table ofcource..

Comment: Thank You @Raymond Nijiland